# DC-DC converter isolation capacitance return path?

Tags: noise, emc, isolation, coupling

For those isolated DC-DC converter bricks like seen in the photo below:
[image]

The data sheet specifies an isolation capacitance in the order of picofarads. And in order to meet EMC requirements they recommend coupling either side of the isolation barrier with a cap to reduce loop area of the current leakage. That part makes sense to me, but I am struggling to see how else the current could return say if the cap weren't there? (assuming the DC-DC converter is the only component "bridging" the two isolated circuits).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the two below circuits. They are identical except for C7 100nF between input and output. There is an unbalanced coupling of 5pF between primary and secondary as shown. Output capacitor is unrealistically low in both cases so it starts up quickly for simulation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fj4VJF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Both circuits provide a stable output voltage of about 25VDC, but the output voltage varies wrt the input ground in the first case.

Without C7 the isolated part of your circuit waggles around all over the place at high frequency. It won't in reality be as bad as the top simulation because there will be stray capacitance between your isolated circuit and earth most likely but that will have a very large loop area.

With C7 the output sits close to the input ground.

However this compromises the AC isolation as you've probably surmised. Aside from making the transformers with fancier construction to minimize the capacitive coupling and divert any such currents to one or more shields, that's kind of the way it is.

Answer (score 3):

So basically the transformer inside the module is driven with a high frequency square wave. There is stray capacitance between transformer primary and secondary side. Since all the other capacitances between the output and input are small, the stray capacitance inside the transformer is more than enough to make the square wave that drives the transformer couple to the isolated output that floats, even if there is very little current flow due to the stray capacitance.

When external capacitance is added between input side and the isolated output, that capacitance is far more greater than the stray capacitance of the transformer, so the small stray capacitance and the extremely small current cannot affect much the voltage of the added capacitor, and therefore the square wave signal from driving the transformer has little effect on the output, as it gets back from the output side via the capacitor to input side.

Answer (score 3):

> but I am struggling to see how else the current could return say if the cap weren't there? (assuming the DC-DC converter is the only component "bridging" the two isolated circuits).

The second 'component' bridging the two isolated circuits is the stray capacitance of the wiring of one side to the wiring of the other. This means that the leakage current might travel a long way into the wiring before it has met enough capacitance to return to the other set of wiring. This makes for a very large loop area. That is why the document you have is worded like that, the extra capacitor reduces the loop area, and thus the radiation efficiency, of the leakage current.